# How to change date format from Excel into SQL Server format

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, database

I have date data from text file, when I read this text file using Excel and change the format into date format then the value changes.

Example data

from text file :

1. 30630
2. 24470
3. 28917

Then change into date format using Excel :

1. 10/11/1983
2. 29/12/1966
3. 03/03/1979

I would like to change the date data from a text file using SQL Server to be like the data contained in Excel, but I could not find a suitable query, please help what kind of query should I write in SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel date numbers are simply the number of days since `1900-01-01` (with [the problem that Excel believes `1900-02-29` existed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year_problem#:%7E:text=Microsoft%20Excel%20), so for simplicity's sake it's the number of days since `1899-12-31`).

```
SELECT
    dateValue, -- a `date`, `datetime`, `datetime2`, or `datetimeoffset` column.
    DATEDIFF( day, '1899-12-31', dateValue ) AS dateAsExcelSerial
FROM
    yourTable
```

To go in reverse (given an Excel date-serial, get a `date` value):

```
SELECT
    excelSerial, -- an `int` column. For real/decimal/float YMMV.
    DATEADD( date, excelSerial, '1899-12-31' ) AS dateValue
FROM
    yourTable
```